Spring Secuirty Oauth2 error While using HttpSecurity On sercurityFilterChain
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method oauth2SecurityFilterChain in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2WebSecurityConfiguration$OAuth2SecurityFilterChainConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' in your configuration.

I got this error while start server
i don't know where is the problem :(
[SecruityConfig.java]
package com.discord.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        
        http
            .csrf((csrfConfig) ->
            csrfConfig.disable()
            )
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeRequests) -> authorizeRequests
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2Login((oauth2) -> oauth2 //
                        .disable()
            )
            ;
        
        return http.build();
    }
}


[apllication-oauth.properties]   (connect by application.properties spring.profiles.include=oauth)

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.discord.client-id= [key here]
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.discord.client-secret= [secret key here]
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.discord.scope=identify,email
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.discord.redirect-uri="http://localhost:80/login"
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.discord.provider=discord
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.discord.client-authentication-method=client_secret_post
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.discord.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.discord.authorization-uri=https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.discord.token-uri=https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.discord.user-info-uri=https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.discord.user-info-authentication-method=header
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.discord.user-name-attribute=response


[LoginController.java]
package com.discord.login;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> hello(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok("HEllo from secure endpoint");
    }
}



discord redirect URI
enter image description here
Whatever i fix Spring Boot Server always crashed while Starting

Please add your dependencies to your question. As a side note, oauth2Login configures authorization-code flow, and the resulting security is based on sessions which is the vector for CSRF attacks. You should really not disable CSRF protection in a security filter-chain where you enable oauth2Login.
